# HTML form action url throws 404 for the php files copied outside subdomain

Tags: php, forms, path

Let's take a look at my files structure.

[image]

Here, the website domain is `abc.com`, and as you can see there is a subdomain there, `grades.abc.com`. There are some php files inside the `grades.abc.com`, for instance `register.php`. This `register.php` both needs to include some files from `processes` folder (please look at the attached image), and also to send requests to some files there. The point is that the includes work in `register.php`, but requests not. Php `includes` use the relative path and find the files in the `processes` folder, but forms in `register.php` cannot find them.

Hence, the following line works in `register.php`:

```
include_once '../processes/dbs.php';
```

However, in the `form` included inside this `register.php`, the action url throws 404, and cannot reach the files inside `processes` folder.

The following code does not work, and it cannot reach

```
<form class="text-left" action="../processes/authenticate.php" method="post">
```

I would be more than grateful if you let me know how to solve the issue.

Comment: Your issue is a bit unclear atm. Please show us your actual file/folder structure and what code, including example data, that causes issues (and explain those issues in more detail. We need more concrete examples than just "say for example" where you explain the structure instead of showing it. It should be more like: "Here's my file/folder structure", "here's my code", "when I do a, b happens while I expect c".

Comment: Also, when you say root, what root are you referring to? Document root? File system root?

Comment: Dear @MagnusEriksson, the question is fully revised. Many thanks beforehand.

Comment: You can not request stuff _above_ the document root of a domain or subdomain via HTTP.

Comment: If `grades.abc.com` is the document root for that subdomain, then clients (the browser) won't be able to access anything that's outside of it. That would be a massive security issue.

Comment: And even using the full absolute URL under the abc.com domain, i.e. `http(s)://abc.com/processes/authenticate.php` likely won't work, because the document root of that is likely set to `public_html`. So the solution would be to target a file _below_ the document root of your subdomain, and have that one _include_ the processing script via the file system again ... or a different structure to begin with.

Comment: Special thanks to CBroe and MagnusErriksson. Hope you will come up with an answer in case it will be useful for other newbies getting stuck like me.